# Result is incorrect with OpenMp

Tags: c++, loops, parallel-processing, openmp, nested-loops

I try to use openmp to get enhancement of loop.

Here is the code:

```
int temppcounter=0;
int pcounter=-1;
int nextX=0;
int nextY=0;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(matArr,visArr,plots) private(nextX,nextY) firstprivate(pcounter) lastprivate(pcounter)
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   
   for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if(matArr[i][j]!= ZERO) {
            continue;
        }
       
        for(int h = 0; h < NSIZE; h++) {
            nextX = i + dx[h];
            nextY = j + dy[h];

            if( nextX < 0 || nextY < 0 || nextX >= rows || nextY >= cols ) {
                continue;
            }
            
            if( !visArr[nextX][nextY] && matArr[nextX][nextY]== ONE){ //(int) image.at<uchar>(nextX, nextY) == ONE ) {
                pcounter++;
                visArr[nextX][nextY] = true;
                matArr[nextX][nextY]=pixelThreshold;
                plots[nextX][nextY]=1;
                plotx[pcounter]=nextX;
                ploty[pcounter]=nextY;
            }
        }
    }
}

#pragma omp parallel for   reduction(+:temppcounter) 
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
        if(plots[i][j]==1){

            temppcounter++;
        }
    }
```

The real number of `plots[i][j]=1` is 382771,but in contrast the number of pcounter is only 147434.If the pcounter is used as shared variable, though I can get 38xxxx, the result is incorrect.

I guess there is some error in pcounter, however, I still haven't figured out the root cause. Could someone kindly provide any hint or suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing ?

Comment: Hello James, thanks for your suggestion.I will take a look at the link you pasted.But I still have one question,if use atomic in one region where the pcounter is,does it mean there is only one thread handling this region instead of parallel threads ?

Comment: First, you have to check if your algorithm can be parallelized or not. It seems to me that you have loop-carried dependencies. What does your algorithm do? Your code seems to process pixels/picture and you may find several existing parallel algorithm/library to do that.

Comment: @Lance it is easy to tell why you get incorrect results: each thread uses a private copy of `pcounter` and there are several potential race conditions in your code and you may also have loop carried dependency. However, it is much more difficult to tell how to parallelize it effectively, if it is possible at all.